# Modifying CSS by inserting variable with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to modify the css of a class using jquery 3 and change the background color.

First I am converting a rgba color code (properties.color) to a hexadecimal code which works perfectly fine.

I then change the background of the „zu-default div“ class using jquery.
This however does not work when I insert the variable „finalcolor“. When I hardcode a hexadecimal color such as „#fec23b“ , the change is visible. When I use the variable „finalcolor“ there is no change.
Printing the variable finalcolor to the console shows that is a perfectly fine hexcode.

Any suggestions?

```
// converts a rgba to hex
 let finalcolor = rgb2hex(properties.color);

    //prints the converted hexadecimal (for eg: #fec23b)
   console.log(finalcolor);

//Should modify the background of the zu-default div class to the color „finalcolor“
$('.zu-default div').css("background", finalcolor);
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduce the issue you describe.

Comment: Did you try doing a hard reload/clearing cache? On chrome, you can do this either by pressing CTRL + SHIFT + R or press F12, right click refresh button and choosing "Empty cache and hard reload"

Comment: And note, if one assign the `finalcolor` variable with e.g. `#fec23b` it works just fine so likely there is something wrong with your conversion.

Comment: The finalcolor variable depends on the current user, but I have tested it and it is always a valid hexadecimal such as #fec23b.

Comment: Are you sure the returned value of `rgb2hex()` is of type `string`?

Comment: Example in studio.

Comment: @ЮрийСветлов As OP says it works when the variable is hardcoded, we don't need to see the class `.zu-default div` ... we need a sample ***reproducing*** the issue though

Comment: @NL97 I answered on your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.zu-default div').css("background", finalcolor+' !important');
```

or

```
$('.zu-default div').css("background", finalcolor.toString());
```

it is Working?

```js
 $('.zu-default div').css("background", 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="zu-default">
            <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
            <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
            <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
        </div>
```

```js
let finalcolor = '#222222';

$('.zu-default div').attr('style', $('.zu-default div').attr('style')+"background: "+finalcolor+";");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <div class="zu-default">
            <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
            <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
            <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
        </div>
```